# Starting off: Adventurer or Trader

Tags: port-royale-3

When I start Port Royale, I have two different campaigns to choose from: Adventurer or Trader.  What are the differences between these campaigns?  Do they play differently?  Is one harder or easier than the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The campaign you want to start with is your preference.

If you're a pirate-kinda guy, you might like adventurer over trader.
If you're more into economics, you should pick trader.

There is noting such as easy or hard, it's just the way you look at it.